# Incompatible packages: 1 Package restore failed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm learning asp.net.
I am following the Microsoft MvcMovie tutorial for Asp.net-Core on a mac. I have done all the steps as the example shows, I go through the 3rd page of the tutorial, but when compiling the code, I am shown the following error:
"The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)."

I tried to update the NuGet packages, an answer I saw on this page. But when I update them, another error appears:

"Incompatible packages: 1
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MvcMovie'. "

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: What kind of .Net Core version you using ? Also .net core sdk version  and can you take a screen shot of the fail message for me to see ?

Comment: If update it the NuGet packages without results then maybe you need to downgrade on of packages tha t gives the error. I'm not really sure because you are not giving much information.